# how do I group two columns's average under another column-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Speed_Vehicles_avg=Urban[['Speed_limit'],['Number_of_Vehicles']].mean().groupby([Urban['Day_Of_Week']])
```

Using the Urban dataframe, I am trying to find the average of the Speed_limit, and Number_of_Vehicles grouping by Day_of_Week. The error message says that it's an invalid key. I am wondering if it's just formatting problem?

Comment: `Urban.groupby('Day_Of_Week')[['Speed_limit', 'Number_of_Vehicles']].mean()`.

Comment: raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'Day_Of_Week'

Comment: Replace `Day_Of_Week` with the actual name of the column?

Comment: sorry it was capitalization